# Applications of matrix Chernoff bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, big-list, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

The Chernoff bound, being a sharp quantitative version of the law of large numbers, is incredibly useful in many contexts. Some general applications that come to mind (which I guess are really the same idea) are:

- bounding the sample complexity of PAC algorithms;
- estimating confidence intervals for polling (somewhat surprisingly, the Chernoff bound tells you that if you want to poll a population of $N$ people, the number $N$ doesn't really matter for the tradeoff between randomly sampled people and accuracy of the empirical average)
- more generally, very often in the analysis of randomized algorithms you need to argue that you have 'enough' samples, and Chernoff bounds are the way to go.

By now I feel like I have a good intuitive grasp of the power and limitations of Chernoff bounds. Basically, my question is about getting a similar understanding of matrix Chernoff bounds:

- How do I obtain a similar palette of 'classical' applications of matrix Chernoff bounds?
- What are some of the nice proofs they give us?
- Have they substantially simplified previous work that didn't explicitly use them?

Comment: Here is another example for matrix Chernoff bounds.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03864.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I think matrix Chernoff bounds are still relatively new, so maybe there aren't really classical applications yet.  But personally, I've used Tropp's monograph (https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01571) and sections 5 and 6 of "Derandomizing the Ahlswede-Winter matrix-valued Chernoff bound using pessimistic estimators, and applications"
 (http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v004a003/) as references for applications.

Some examples of matrix Chernoff bounds simplifying previous work include the Alon-Roichman theorem (simplified here -
 http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r62) and results on Matrix Completion (simplified here - http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0651).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question a bit, I've recently learned that Kyng and Sachdeva have used some matrix concentration inequalities to give a very simple Laplacian solver algorithm; paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02353.pdf).